# Is Automatic Reference Counting now supported for i386?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, automatic-ref-counting

As of Xcode 7.3, ARC seems to be working for 32-bit i386 projects. There's no longer a compile error and zeroing out weak references even works. It's even working when running on 10.10. However, I haven't been able to find any documentation stating that 32-bit ARC is officially supported and fully functional. I did find this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/38934 - which notes that "We are in the process of implementing weak references in all Objective-C language modes."

So - does anyone know if ARC is now safe to use for the few remaining cases where a 32-bit i386 binary is needed?

Comment: I'm confused. I've been using ARC with Objective-C since Xcode 4.2. I've been using with iOS app, not macOS app, but I'd be really surprised if ARC hasn't been working on macOS (OS X then) since it worked fine back then for i386 iOS simulator builds.

Comment: It's worked for 64-bit targets, but not for 32-bit targets.